# cURL вставить код перед </body>

Tags: php

Получаю содержимое страницы с другого сайта с помощью cURL.
Столкнулся с проблемой загрузки стилей если в пути нет доменного имени, решил проблему путем добавления `<base href="http://донор/">`

Получилось `<base href="http://донор/"><!DOCTYPE html>`
Можно встроить `<base href="http://донор/">` после `<!DOCTYPE html>` т.е. внедрить в теги `<head></head>`?

Как добавить свой код перед `</body>` все в том же полученном с помощью cURL коде?

Спасибо!

Сам код:

```
<base href="http://донор/">

<?php 
// инициализация сеанса 

$ch = curl_init(); 

// установка URL и других необходимых параметров 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://донор"); 

// загрузка страницы и выдача её браузеру 
curl_exec($ch); 

// завершение сеанса и освобождение ресурсов 
curl_close($ch); 
?>
```

Comment: Уберите `<base href="донор/">` из первой строки и удалите два перевода строк.

Comment: если убрать <base href="донор/"> не загрузятся стили и картинки...

Comment: т.е. я хочу изменить полученный с помощью cURL - код.

Comment: Ну так не выводите ее в браузер сразу, а грузите в переменную. Далее меняйте, что вам нужно внутри переменной работая с содержимым как со строкой. А потом измененное содержимое выводите в браузер.

Comment: :) спасибо, поищу. Мало представляю как это реализовать...